# how can we have a sound pcm wav little endian (mono) in output

Tags: pcm, qtkit

can you please help me retrieve the wav format  pcm but in little endian (mono)
you will find my code as an attachment
[code source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVCaptureToAudioUnitOSX/Listings/CaptureSessionController_mm.html)

Comment: My code -> "This Apple software is supplied to you by Apple". Somehow I don't think that's your code. Furthermore, if your WAV file is stereo, you can't just retrieve that in mono.